# .htaccess redirect php WHMCS cart ID

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

For WHMCS I am trying to redirect products to another ID and subdomain.

How can I create a `.htaccess` that will redirect

```
https://www.example.com/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=17
```

to

```
https://clients.example.com/cart.php?a=add&pid=55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the query string is always exactly as written. ie. just two URL parameters and in the order: `a` first, followed by `pid`. Then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=add&pid=17$
RewriteRule ^(clients)/(cart\.php)$ https://$1.example.com/$2?a=add&pid=55 [R=302,L]
```

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences simply save repetition as they contain the captured subgroups from the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

If, however, the URL parameters could be in any order and there might be other URL params (that should be discarded) then you would need to modify the *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) like so:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)a=add(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pid=17(&|$)
:
```

If you have many such redirects then they can be simplified, either by using a `RewriteMap` (defined in the server config) or perhaps a secondary `.htaccess` file in a specific subdirectory, if you do not have access to the server config. Or root such requests to a server-side PHP script that handles the redirect.

Comment: What if I want to modify multiple for example pid=18 then to pid=59

Comment: @Toodarday How many? If it's just a few (dozen or so) then just repeat the above rule as many times as required. Otherwise, what access to the server do you have? Server config, `.htaccess` only or PHP? What is the reason for this redirect? Have URLs changed? Is this permanent?